# cmd output to textbox repeating lines

Tags: c#, outputstream

I am trying to make a test program for a feature I want to put into a bigger project. I am trying to get the Output of a batch file into a textbox to act as an inapp command prompt output that the user could then interact with through the app. User input will come later. So far, I have the app working so it reads the batch output in realtime. However every time it updates, it takes an exact copy of everything that is supposed to be displayed in the cmd and pastes it directly below the previous output. As a test I made a simple batch script that pings 8.8.8.8 continuously with a -t argument. Here is my code so far.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleOutput_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static StringBuilder sortOutput = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Process sortProcess;
            sortProcess = new Process();
            sortProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "test.bat";
            // Set UseShellExecute to false for redirection.
            sortProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            sortProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;



            // Redirect the standard output of the sort command.  
            // This stream is read asynchronously using an event handler.
            sortProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            sortOutput = new StringBuilder("");

            // Set our event handler to asynchronously read the sort output.
            sortProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);

            // Redirect standard input as well.  This stream
            // is used synchronously.
            sortProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

            // Start the process.
            sortProcess.Start();



            // Start the asynchronous read of the sort output stream.
            sortProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
            while (!sortProcess.HasExited)
            {
                Application.DoEvents(); // This keeps your form responsive by processing events
            }
        }

        private void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess,
            DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
        {
            if (txtConsole.InvokeRequired) { txtConsole.BeginInvoke(new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler), new[] { sendingProcess, outLine }); }
            else
            {
            sortOutput.Append(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
            txtConsole.AppendText(sortOutput.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So now we are at where my problem lies. When I run the program, it displays what I want in realtime, however it copy and pastes the updated output and pastes it into the textbox right below the last update. Example below:

```
G:\ConsoleOutput test\ConsoleOutput Test\bin\Debug>ping 8.8.8.8 -t

G:\ConsoleOutput test\ConsoleOutput Test\bin\Debug>ping 8.8.8.8 -t

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:

G:\ConsoleOutput test\ConsoleOutput Test\bin\Debug>ping 8.8.8.8 -t

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8:bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=253


G:\ConsoleOutput test\ConsoleOutput Test\bin\Debug>ping 8.8.8.8 -t

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8:bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=253
Reply from 8.8.8.8:bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=253

G:\ConsoleOutput test\ConsoleOutput Test\bin\Debug>ping 8.8.8.8 -t

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8:bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=253
Reply from 8.8.8.8:bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=253
Reply from 8.8.8.8:bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=253

etc
```

The output just keeps continuing on like this. I want to display the output exactly as the it would appear in a cmd window.

```
    G:\ConsoleOutput test\ConsoleOutput Test\bin\Debug>ping 8.8.8.8 -t

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8:bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=253
Reply from 8.8.8.8:bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=253
Reply from 8.8.8.8:bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=253
Reply from 8.8.8.8:bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=253
Reply from 8.8.8.8:bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=253
Reply from 8.8.8.8:bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=253
Reply from 8.8.8.8:bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=253
Reply from 8.8.8.8:bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=253
Reply from 8.8.8.8:bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=253
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its doing exactly what your code says to do

```
      sortOutput.Append(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
        txtConsole.AppendText(sortOutput.ToString());
```

you say add the new line to the SortOutput, then add all of sort output to text box. You will obviously get repeated lines

just do

```
        txtConsole.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
```

Comment: omfg, I'm an idiot. Thank you so much, I was ripping my hair out trying to solve this.